# Mac Automation / Scripting: create reminder item for each calendar event

Tags: automation, javascript-automation

I would like to automatically create a reminder item for each event in a particular calendar. Below is my automation script (JavaScript). `CALENDAR_NAME` is the source calendar name, `REMINDER_LIST_NAME` the target reminder list name.

```
// `osascript ./calender-to-reminder.js`

const CALENDAR_NAME = 'TODO';
const REMINDER_LIST_NAME = 'TODO';

const Calendar = Application('Calendar');
const Reminders = Application('Reminders');

const workCalendar = Calendar.calendars.byName(CALENDAR_NAME);
const calendarItems = workCalendar.events();

const reminderList = Reminders.lists.byName(REMINDER_LIST_NAME);

for (let i = 0; i < calendarItems.length; i++) {
    const calendarItem = calendarItems[i];
    const reminderName = calendarItem.summary();
    const reminderNote = calendarItem.description();
    const reminderDueDate = calendarItem.startDate();

    // Check if reminder with the same name already exists
    const existingReminders = reminderList.reminders().filter(
        r => r.name() === reminderName && r.dueDate() === reminderDueDate
    );
    if (existingReminders.length > 0) {
        // Reminder already exists, update its note
        const reminderToUpdate = existingReminders[0];
        reminderToUpdate.body.set(reminderNote);
    } else {
        // Reminder doesn't exist, create a new one
        const newReminder = Reminders.Reminder({
            name: reminderName,
            dueDate: reminderDueDate,
            body: reminderNote
        });
        reminderList.reminders.push(newReminder);
    }
}
```

While the script works, it's incredibly slow and only creates a few items **per hour**. During the entire time, the Reminder app is almost unresponsive. Since I'm trying to create a few hundred reminder items, the script would need days to complete. The source calendar is a subscribed calendar. I'm on macOS 13.2.1.

Does anybody know what the issue is and what I could change to make the script complete the work in a reasonable amount of time?